# Changing default font of labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I've just opened a [feature request](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10387), but maybe someone knows a temporary solution.

In QGIS 2.2 one can change the default font of the Print Composer (through the Menu Option -> Setttings). But I think it is not possible to do the same with labels.

This is a little bit boring when one has to export a project from a Linux to a Windows machine. In Linux (debian in my case) the default font in Cantarell, font that is not recognized by Windows.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Would be very worthwhile!

Comment: Hi @Simbamangu, unfortunately not yet. If you take a look at the link of the feature request you will see that it is still open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a workaround (or even a solution) you can create a variable (project or global based) with the default font - maybe one that is found on both OSs?

To do that, you can create either a project based variable (only applies to that project) or a global variable (applies to every qgis project).

To make a global variable, click **Settings** > **Options** > **Variables** (pane on left).

To make a project based variable, do this through **Project** > **Project Properties** > **Variables**.

Once you decide if you'd like a project or global variable, hit the green **+** sign, and for example, make a variable called `def_font` and with the value `Comic Sans`.

`def_font        Comic Sans`

Now you can use that variable as the font through a **data defined override (expression)**. See screenshot below where that variable can be applied from **Layer Properties** > **Label** (tab)

[image: font variable usage in qgis]

Now that variable can be applied to each layer that would use that font, and if you ever need to change the font (for those 20 layers!) just change the `def_font` variable and voila - it updates all layers referencing that variable.

---

The above example shows how to change the font face/family but other variables can be created for other font styling changes like bold, size, placement, etc.

Comment: it is possible thanks to the Variable introduction in the last QGIS releases. but, in fact, this is the solution to an old problem

Comment: Doesn't work for the print composer labels unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, to change the "Default" Text-Style in the "Style Manager":
https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/style_manager.html
This style then is used for new labels (at least in my case).
Likely it is as well possible to overwrite the default text style with a new style called "Default".

I hope that this is fairly stable, but I'm just starting to test it.