# Setting default label font in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, labeling, font

QGIS currently does not have a way to set a default font to be used for labelling, and being lazy I'm getting tired of having to set our house font styling for every layer I create or use (see [change default font of labels in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98319/change-default-font-of-labels-in-qgis) for someone else equally frustrated, and the bug report for it).

I've looked at the QGIS code changes required and it's not easy, so now I'm trying for an interim fix by writing a plugin that will either apply a default qml style file or directly set it via the api.

A couple of approaches I'm contemplating are:

- A legend context menu entry (easy to do, expandable to choosing from a list of house styles, but still a manual process)
- Catching the layerAdded signal, checking if the new layer has a style already set, and if not setting the font (more complex but fully automatic)

Before I do this, can anyone suggest a simpler hack, or something obvious I'm missing? Something using project templates, default styles, layer definition files, or something similar?

(I'm aware this won't work when using rule-based labeling, but for most use cases it will make life easier).

Comment: Have you seen the answer provided by @SaultDon in your linked post?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't make it any quicker, you're still having to choose a value from a drop-down, just a shorter one, and you still have to choose size and style too. A single click or no click solution would be better.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround I've found is to open up the `.qgs` project file in a text editor (they're in a sort of plain-text `xml` type format) after the fact and batch change all the font declarations with regex - I think they should ALL be in the `.qgs` file, unless perhaps there are some plug-ins that store them elsewhere.

Sorry I don't remember exactly what they look like in the text as haven't used QGIS for a little while but they should be obvious - if you don't know how to use regex let me know.